# I can't find the issue in my simple password generater, written in c#

Tags: c#, security, random, passwords, generator

So i just wrote the code for the c# random password generator, tried to compile but it didn't work in the end. I just started as I would do it normal, but after a while many issues showed up that i didn't understand. I already did another password genrater, but in javascript. I started c# a year ago or smth, i'm not that good. I really can't find the issue i made. Maybe somebody else could help me and correct it. Thank you. Here's the code:

```
namespace WorkingCode.CodeProject.PwdGen
{
    using System;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;

    public class PasswordGenerator
    {
        public PasswordGenerator() 
        {
            this.Minimum               = DefaultMinimum;
            this.Maximum               = DefaultMaximum;
            this.ConsecutiveCharacters = false;
            this.RepeatCharacters      = true;
            this.ExcludeSymbols        = false;
            this.Exclusions            = null;

            rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        }       
        
        protected int GetCryptographicRandomNumber(int lBound, int uBound)
        {   
            // Assumes lBound >= 0 && lBound < uBound
            // returns an int >= lBound and < uBound
            uint urndnum;   
            byte[] rndnum = new Byte[4];   
            if (lBound == uBound-1)  
            {
                // test for degenerate case where only lBound can be returned
                return lBound;
            }
                                                              
            uint xcludeRndBase = (uint.MaxValue -
                (uint.MaxValue%(uint)(uBound-lBound)));   
            
            do 
            {      
                rng.GetBytes(rndnum);      
                urndnum = System.BitConverter.ToUInt32(rndnum,0);      
            } while (urndnum >= xcludeRndBase);   
            
            return (int)(urndnum % (uBound-lBound)) + lBound;
        }

        protected char GetRandomCharacter()
        {            
            int upperBound = pwdCharArray.GetUpperBound(0);

            if ( true == this.ExcludeSymbols )
            {
                upperBound = PasswordGenerator.UBoundDigit;
            }

            int randomCharPosition = GetCryptographicRandomNumber(
                pwdCharArray.GetLowerBound(0), upperBound);

            char randomChar = pwdCharArray[randomCharPosition];

            return randomChar;
        }
        
        public string Generate()
        {
            // Pick random length between minimum and maximum   
            int pwdLength = GetCryptographicRandomNumber(this.Minimum,
                this.Maximum);

            StringBuilder pwdBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            pwdBuffer.Capacity = this.Maximum;

            // Generate random characters
            char lastCharacter, nextCharacter;

            // Initial dummy character flag
            lastCharacter = nextCharacter = '\n';

            for ( int i = 0; i < pwdLength; i++ )
            {
                nextCharacter = GetRandomCharacter();

                if ( false == this.ConsecutiveCharacters )
                {
                    while ( lastCharacter == nextCharacter )
                    {
                        nextCharacter = GetRandomCharacter();
                    }
                }

                if ( false == this.RepeatCharacters )
                {
                    string temp = pwdBuffer.ToString();
                    int duplicateIndex = temp.IndexOf(nextCharacter);
                    while ( -1 != duplicateIndex )
                    {
                        nextCharacter = GetRandomCharacter();
                        duplicateIndex = temp.IndexOf(nextCharacter);
                    }
                }

                if ( ( null != this.Exclusions ) )
                {
                    while ( -1 != this.Exclusions.IndexOf(nextCharacter) )
                    {
                        nextCharacter = GetRandomCharacter();
                    }
                }

                pwdBuffer.Append(nextCharacter);
                lastCharacter = nextCharacter;
            }

            if ( null != pwdBuffer )
            {
                return pwdBuffer.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return String.Empty;
            }   
        }
            
        public string Exclusions
        {
            get { return this.exclusionSet;  }
            set { this.exclusionSet = value; }
        }

        public int Minimum
        {
            get { return this.minSize; }
            set 
            { 
                this.minSize = value;
                if ( PasswordGenerator.DefaultMinimum > this.minSize )
                {
                    this.minSize = PasswordGenerator.DefaultMinimum;
                }
            }
        }

        public int Maximum
        {
            get { return this.maxSize; }
            set 
            { 
                this.maxSize = value;
                if ( this.minSize >= this.maxSize )
                {
                    this.maxSize = PasswordGenerator.DefaultMaximum;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool ExcludeSymbols
        {
            get { return this.hasSymbols; }
            set { this.hasSymbols = value;}
        }

        public bool RepeatCharacters
        {
            get { return this.hasRepeating; }
            set { this.hasRepeating = value;}
        }

        public bool ConsecutiveCharacters
        {
            get { return this.hasConsecutive; }
            set { this.hasConsecutive = value;}
        }

        private const int DefaultMinimum = 6;
        private const int DefaultMaximum = 10;
        private const int UBoundDigit    = 61;

        private RNGCryptoServiceProvider    rng;
        private int             minSize;
        private int             maxSize;
        private bool            hasRepeating;
        private bool            hasConsecutive;
        private bool            hasSymbols;
        private string          exclusionSet;
        private char[] pwdCharArray = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\\|;:'\",<>/?".ToCharArray();
```

Comment: _"tried to compile but it didn't work in the end"_ What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one-liner instead of your multiple lines:

```
private char[] pwdCharArray = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\\|;:'\",<>/?".ToCharArray();
```

or put it in brackets:

```
private char[] pwdCharArray = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFG" +
        "HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\\|;:'\",<" +
         ".>/?").ToCharArray();
```